# How to get rssi value of a connected Bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I am trying to get the rssi value of a connected bluetooth device in my android program.
Below is the code:

```
gatt = mDevice.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);
        Log.d(TAG, "rssi is : " + rssi);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rssiValue)).setText(rssi);
    }
});
gatt.readRemoteRssi();
```

But the method **onReadRemoteRssi** doesnot return any value.
Please help me with the issue.

Comment: Please check if you device is connected or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RSSI.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
     RSSI.this, 
     new String[] { 
       Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
       Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
       Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
     },
     1
   );
```

}

1. Make sure that the ***mDevice*** variable retrieved from BlueetoothAdapter is not null
2. Lastly make sure the permissions are set, the above code will give you required privileges to get Bluetooth bonded device(s).